# How to use multiple CustomCells with UISegmentedControl Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a small issue with the multiple CustomCells by using SegmentedControl. I have imported a framework HMSegmentedControl with 4 segmentedcontrols like (Admin, Engineer, Doctor, Employee). Now the problem is how to use multiple custom cells like (AdminCellList, EngineerCellList, DoctorCellList, EmployeeListCell). When Admin SegmentedControl is Clicked AdminCellList should be loaded and so on. Following is what i have tried. TIA.

```
MYViewController.h

@interface MYViewController : UIViewController
{
NSUInteger currentScreen;
}

MYViewController.m

self.AdminView.hidden = NO;
    self.EngineerView.hidden = YES;
    self.DoctorView.hidden = YES;
    self.EmployeeView.hidden = YES;


    currentScreen=0;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.AdminView];

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;


    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);

    HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"Admin", @"Engineer", @"Doctor", @"Employee"]];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewWidth, 45);
    segmentedControl.selectionStyle = HMSegmentedControlSelectionStyleFullWidthStripe;

    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:170/255.0 green:170/255.0 blue:170/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    segmentedControl.selectionIndicatorHeight = 2.0f;
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerEnabled = YES;
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    segmentedControl.verticalDividerWidth = 1.0f;
    segmentedControl.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    [segmentedControl setTitleFormatter:^NSAttributedString *(HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl, NSString *title, NSUInteger index, BOOL selected) {
        NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
        return attString;
    }];

    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
}


- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{

    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        currentScreen=0;

       //Loading Service
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        currentScreen=1;

        //Loading Service
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        currentScreen=2;

        //Loading Service
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {
        currentScreen=3;

        //Loading Service
    }

}


- (void)uisegmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    NSLog(@"Selected index %ld", (long)segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 10;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    AdminCellList *cell = (AdminCellList *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AdminCellList" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (AdminCellList *) currentObject;
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}
```

Comment: your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code is incomplete.

Comment: i can;t understand how to get multiple customcells there. So i wrote only one customcell

Comment: Have you tried below code?

Comment: tried but not worked

Comment: update your question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good, just need some additions:

1.Reload table each time user changes segment.

2.Put check inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` according to `currentScreen` and load corresponding cell with custom class.

```
- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(UISegmentedControl *)segment {

    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        currentScreen=0;
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        currentScreen=1;
    }
    ....... more code

    [myTableView reloadData];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        if (currentScreen == 0) {
            AdminCellList *cell = (AdminCellList *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {

                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AdminCellList" owner:self options:nil];

                for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                        cell =  (AdminCellList *) currentObject;
                        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (currentScreen == 1) {
            //Same code for cell as AdminCellList
            EngineerCellList *cell = (EngineerCellList *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {

                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EngineerCellList" owner:self options:nil];

                for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                        cell =  (EngineerCellList *) currentObject;
                        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (currentScreen == 2) {
            //Similar custom cell code here as above
        } else {
            //Similar custom cell code here as above
        }
}
```